# ngWYSIWYG - Angular real rich text editor not able to edit inside bpopup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rich-text-editor, bpopup

I am using ngWYSIWYG - Angular real rich text editor http://psergus.github.io/ngWYSIWYG/ inside bpopup but its coming as not able to editable

```
 $scope.editorConfig = {
    sanitize: false,
    toolbar: [
        { name: 'basicStyling', items: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', '-', 'leftAlign', 'centerAlign', 'rightAlign', 'blockJustify', '-'] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items: ['orderedList', 'unorderedList', 'outdent', 'indent', '-'] },
        { name: 'doers', items: ['removeFormatting', 'undo', 'redo', '-'] },
        { name: 'colors', items: ['fontColor', 'backgroundColor', '-'] },
        { name: 'links', items: ['image', 'hr', 'symbols', 'link', 'unlink', '-'] },
        { name: 'tools', items: ['print', '-'] },
        { name: 'styling', items: ['font', 'size', 'format'] },
    ]
};
 <wysiwyg-edit content="your_variable"  config="editorConfig"></wysiwyg-edit>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. I know this isn't ideal, but here's how I solved it:

- If you're using a CDN, use bower to pull ngWYSIWYG into your project
- Edit the dist/wysiwyg.min.js

  - Ctrl + F for:

> {name:"basicStyling",items:["bold","italic","underline""

- That is the start of the toolbar options so edit them however you'd like!

Wish I knew of a better fix, but that's what worked for me.